# Is there a way to do what is in the third and fourth instance in a different way this doesn't work

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

The code is about employee salary management, but we are also trying to automate some of the code by not requiring the user to input the proper syntax but rather the just the values such as in a create table statement.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
while True: 
print("1.C&L")
print("2.Cursor Define")
print("3.Create Table")
print("4.Insert Data into Table")
a=int(input("Enter Choice(0 to exit)"))
if a==0:
    break
if a==1:
     db=mysql.connect(
         host='localhost',
         user='root',
         passwd='12345',
         database='opip'
     ) 
     print(db)   
if a==2:
    curs=db.cursor()
    print(curs)
if a==3:
    print("CREATE TABLE [table_name] ([column_name] [data_type][data_size])")
    z=input("Type the above syntax with correct variables")
    curs.execute(z)

if a==4:
    x="""INSERT into opip(id,Name,Age,DOB,Position,Salary)VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    data=input("Provide Values") 
    curs.execute(x,data)
    db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this in two ways

1. Recursively read the input for each of your placeholders [table_name],[column_name],[data_type],[data_size] until an end flag determined by you is read.

   ```
    table=input("Table Name ")
    columnName=input("Column Name ")
    columnType=input("Column Data Type ")
    columnSize=input("Column Size ")
   ```
2. Read everything in a single input and then split it into respective types to populate your template

   ```
    txt = input()
    values = txt.split()
    dbString = "CREATE TABLE " + values[0] + "(" # Start Syntax

    i=1
    while i < len(values):
        dbString += values[i] + " " # Column Name
        i += 1

        dbString += values[i] + "(" # Column Data Type
        i += 1

        dbString += values[i] + ")" # Column Size
        i += 1

        if i < len(values):
          dbString += ", " # prepare for next column details

    dbString += ")" # End Syntax

    curs.execute(dbString) # Execute Dynamic SQL
   ```

For Input

> mytable col1 char 2 col2 char 3

DbString Output

> CREATE TABLE mytable(col1 char(2), col2 char(3))